# how can i make my function more efficient?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement

hey guys i wrote a function that compares array values and returns the minimum value but i want to know if there are ways to make it more efficient like iterating through all arrays (using one loop) and putting the results in a new array or making individual arrays sub-arrays of a single array, etc. Also the function provides the correct output but prints the answer three times:

```
var nums1 = [-7528819, 3927361, -6398192];
var nums2 = [1777100, -2299720, -5566643];
var nums3 = [7188445, 3724971, 7699332];
var nums4 = [-8432528, -159836, -1604959];
var nums5 = [2764889, 4681472, 701396];
var nums6 = [-5073513, 599535, 4388457];
var nums7 = [8689640, 8028586, 1022322];
var nums8 = [-1088592, 1211232, -7868192];
var nums9 = [-5848613, -4945165, 631213];
var nums10 = [3218429, -833619, -1495854];
var nums11 = [8007060, 1637562, -7568493];
var nums12 = [-8391131, -6585338, 131787];
var nums13 = [-3957775, -9396892, -6143241];
var nums14 = [-6258442, -7829421, 3696922];
var nums15 = [2136598, 4935467, -1621605];
var nums16 = [-7162005, 9861954, 8977930];
var nums17 = [7226452, 8551594, 7006517];
var nums18 = [-1751226, -2536997, -1782251];
var nums19 = [380582, 1614389, 3272584];
var nums20 = [-8988205, -5167181, -7561034];
var nums21 = [-484059, -7160121, 4076528];
var nums22 = [1947448, -5551253, 7491190];

var numsLength = nums1.length;
var i = 0;
var minNum;

function test(arr) {
    for (i; i < numsLength; i++) {
        if (arr[0] < arr[1] && arr[2]) {
            minNum = arr[0];

        } else if (arr[1] < arr[2] && arr[0]) {
            minNum = arr[1];

        } else if (arr[2] < arr[1] && arr[0]) {
            minNum = arr[2];
        }
        console.log(minNum);
    }
}

test(nums1);
```

Comment: Why do you have a loop if you don't use `i`?

Comment: And because `console.log` is in the useless loop, it outputs the result 3 times...

Comment: Trying to clarify your question, are you asking on how to loop through nums1..nums22 and get an array which contains the minimum number of each numsX array?

Comment: the loop is useless, i see. To DJ ], yes that is basically what i'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `Math.min` function.

```
console.log(Math.min.apply(null, nums1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at his snippet of code and read inline comments:

```
var nums = [];

// I'm pushing only 3 sets of data, but there can be any number
// Also there can be any number of elements in each array as you can see
nums.push([-7528819, 3927361, -6398192]);
nums.push([1777100, -2299720, -5566643, 380582]);
nums.push([7188445, 3724971, 7699332, 1947448, -5551253, 7491190]);

function produceResults(nums) {
    var i,
        results = [];

    // gathering results
    for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        results.push(Math.min.apply(null, nums[i]));
    }

    return results;
}

console.log(produceResults(nums));
```

So 2 suggestions:

1. use more dynamic structure (array of arrays) instead of
   defining 22 arrays.
2. use built in JS functions and components ([Math.min](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min))

Comment: in your example, how would the numbers be input into the formed arrays?

Comment: @KeithGray I edited my answer - hope it's cleaner now. You can paste this code directly to JS console (e.g. in Chrome Web Dev Tools) to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Unrolling a loop is actually the most efficient implementation of a loop in most cases.  However, practically speaking, unrolling a loop isn't usually feasible.  With a small, fixed-size array, like those you have here, each permutation of the loop is obvious, and if your goal is raw speed you can't get much more efficient than what you have.  That being said, the loop in your function is useless, as others have pointed out., because you've essentially unrolled the loop already.  Also the syntax of the if statement is incorrect, and you are not handling the case where values in the array are equal.  For fixed arrays of size three you want something more along the lines of...

```
if (val1 <= val2 && val1 <= val3) {
    minVal = val1;
} else if (val2 <= val1 && val2 <= val3) {
    minVal = val2;
} else minVal = val3;
```

Now if you want to do an arbitrary search for the min value of any size array you would do something similar, but using a loop, like...

```
var minVal = null;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (minVal === null || minVal > (val = arr[i]))
        minVal = val;
}
```

Depending on what you actually want to accomplish, and the size of the array, it might make sense to sort the array and rerurn the min (0 index) from the sorted array. If you go that route, start with a google search for "sort algorithms"